# Updating just day from an existent dateandtime column for all table

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, sql-update

I'm trying to create a query that updates the timestamp of all existent rows of a specific table.

Below is an example table to exemplify:

```
"DateAndTime";       ID; value
"2014-04-01 00:00:03";  44;  10
"2014-04-01 00:00:03";  45 ; 120
"2014-04-01 00:00:03";  46 ; 80
"2014-04-01 00:00:03";  47 ; 30000
"2014-04-01 00:00:13";  44 ; 11
"2014-04-01 00:00:13";  45 ; 122
"2014-04-01 00:00:13";  46 ; 76
"2014-04-01 00:00:13";  47 ; 30200
```

Now I want to change JUST the day by the current date but maintain the time
the result would be something like

```
"DateAndTime"     |  ID| value
Current_date + '00:00:03';  44;  10
Current_date + '00:00:03';  45;  120
Current_date + '00:00:03';  46;  80
Current_date + '00:00:03';  47;  30000
Current_date + 00:00:13";  44;  11
Current_date + 00:00:13";  45;  122
Current_date + 00:00:13";  46;  76
Current_date + 00:00:13";  47;  30200
```

I know that I can do the following

```
UPDATE "MyTable"
SET "DateAndTime"= (Select date_trunc('day',Localtimestamp) + ''00:00:03' )
```

And this works,  But I have thousands of rows so i need replace + ''00:00:03' by each row dateandtime column default value with all time extracted. Like if there was an inverted date_trunc witch truncates from the seconds until the hours.

Do you now what can I use to replace the time with the default row value. Or do you know a better way to implement this query.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update MyTable set DateAndTime = now()::date + DateAndTime::time;
```

Comment: thanks, those where the functions that I was searching for initially, but the I found the age solution. Thanks for showing me these way of access the timmestamps sections.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution; Instead of trying to manipulate separatly the date and time I just need to find the difference between the current_timmestamp and the timmestamp that I want to update and add that interval

The code is :

```
UPDATE "MyTable"
SET "DateAndTime"= "DateAndTime" + age(date_trunc('day',"DateAndTime"));
```

You have to trunc the timestamp by the day so the hours, minutes, second and beyond does not enter in the equation.